# www links not working in apache

Tags: apache2

I have setup my apache virtualhosts like this below,  `https://sub.domain.com` works

But if I try `https://www.sub.domain.com` it doesnt work with the `www`. before the domain

I assume this is serveralias? I think it set it up correctly though..

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName sub.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.sub.domain.com
......
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName sub2.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.sub2.domain.com
......
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another `<VirtualHost>` section with this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub2.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.sub2.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache automatically preserves anything after the `/` when using the `Redirect` directive, which is a common misconception about why this method won't work (when in fact it does).